# Is it possible to display the email-style keyboard with Sencha touch + Phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch, android-softkeyboard

Sencha touch has an xtype called "emailfield" that shows the email-styled keyboard on the iPhone. However, it doesn't display the [email-styled keyboard on the Android](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/on-screen-inputs.html).

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<input type="email" />` does the trick in regular old HTML, which Phonegap and Sencha are both built on top of.